# How to run spring batch job on adhoc basis without job parameters?

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, restart

I am writing a spring batch to read data from one database to writing to other database in spring batch . I will be running the job manually on adhoc basis(roughly once in a month) based on business requirements.

My problem is if i don’t add any job parameter then my job will be treated as the same job instance every time once it is successfully completed . How can i rerun the job after successful completion ?

If i pass current timestamp in job parameter or use (new incrementer)  . If it fails , i am rerunning the job & it is creating a new instance  since i had used timestamp or (new incrementer ).

I am thinking of passing job name through .properties file . I will change the job name every time i want to rerun the job after successful completion. Is there any better solution i can go with? 
I have attached my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Db2MySqlLoadApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addDate("date" ,new Date())
            .toJobParameters();

    jobLauncher.run(job,params);



}
   @Bean
public Job cdsRead(Step stepA)
{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("CDS-LOAD-JOB")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepA)
            .build();


}


@Bean
 public Step stepA(ItemReader<RecData> itemReader , ItemWriter<RecData> itemWriter)
{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("REC-LOAD-STEP")
            .<RecData, RecData>chunk(10000)
            .reader(itemReader)
            .processor(itemProcessor())
            .writer(itemWriter)
            .build();
}
```

When i ran with above code for the first time and it failed. I see this in my console :-
Job launched with the following parameters: [{date=1589907545476}]

I am trying to restart this job and i am passing the failed job parameter "1589907545476" in intellij . I was expecting my job to get restarted infact it created a new instance and ran "launched with the following parameters: [{date=1589907885859}]"

Do i need to change my run(String... args)  method in order to accept the parameter first rather than creating every time.

I would really appreciate if you can help me with the code if i am missing anything here in order to accept job parameter of failed job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have attached my code in my original question. I am simply rerunning this on my IDE intelliJ . How can we pass parameters ? Wouldn't i need to handle logic in my code in order to accepts parameters on run time because right now i am fetching the date in my program itself.   Could you please help me the code to handle this .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply  ! it is not working for me . I am sure that i am missing something here which you have stated . I have added more details in my original question. I would really appreciate if you can review and help me here .

Answer (score 1):

> How can i rerun the job after successful completion ?

That is impossible by design. A job instance can only be run once to completion. Please refer to the [Batch domain language](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/domain.html#domainLanguageOfBatch) section for more details.

> If i pass current timestamp in job parameter or use (new incrementer) . If it fails , i am rerunning the job & it is creating a new instance since i had used timestamp or (new incrementer ).

If it is creating a new job instance, this means you are not passing the same parameters as the previous failed execution. Make sure to pass the same **identifying** job parameters to restart the the same instance.